# Add-Migration: The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to do an Entity Framework code-first migration in an Azure Mobile Service. I have the project running locally and add this new class to my model:

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using System;

namespace VCollectAPI.DataObjects
{
    public class TagEdit : EntityData
    {
        public string EditedTagId { get; set; }
        public string SourceTagName { get; set; }
        public string ResultingTagName { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfEdit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also add this property to my VCollectAPIContext:DbContext class

```cs
public DbSet<TagEdit> TagEdits { get; set; }
```

and add a line to my TagDomainManager:EntityDomainManager class

```cs
if (changedItems.Contains("Name"))
{
    _context.TagEdits.Add(new TagEdit { EditedTagId = current.Id, SourceTagName = current.Name, ResultingTagName = update.Name, TimeOfEdit = DateTime.UtcNow });
    current.Name = update.Name;
}
```

At the PMC (Package Manager Console) I then run the command

`Add-Migration RecordingTagEdits -Verbose`

I expect that to make the migration scaffolding the schema update to add the new table. Instead I get the error "The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception."

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

The full error trace is:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Net.ComNetOS' threw an exception. --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The element
>    may only appear once in this section.
>   (C:\TFS\HXDMSRC\VisualCollections\Development\VCollectAPI\tmp140.tmp
>   line 16)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[]
>   keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult,
>   Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()    at
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()    at
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()    at
>   System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()    at
>   System.Net.Logging.get_On()    at System.Net.ComNetOS..cctor()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.ServicePointManager..cctor()    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.ServicePointManager.EnsureStrongCryptoSettingsInitialized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.InitializeNewDomain(AppDomainSetup
>   appDomainInfo)    at System.AppDomain.CreateAppDomainManager()    at
>   System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)    at
>   System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup
>   setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo,
>   IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)    at
>   System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomainHelper(String friendlyName,
>   Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)    at
>   System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence
>   securityInfo, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)    at
>   System.AppDomain.InternalCreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence
>   securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)    at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence
>   securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade..ctor(String
>   migrationsAssemblyName, String contextAssemblyName, String
>   configurationTypeName, String workingDirectory, String
>   configurationFilePath, String dataDirectory, DbConnectionInfo
>   connectionStringInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String
>   configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager'
>   threw an exception.

Answer (score 11):

Check you web.config , maybe have some parameter duplicate.

Comment: great job! This helped me 100%

Answer (score 1):

I had next inner exception, which means my `connectionStrings` section was upper than `configSections`:

`Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element`